# JSF bigger sample codes/projects?

Tags: java, jsf

Does somebody know about resource containing some **bigger** JSF sample projects?
I know about lots of one-bean/one-class/very-small samples (e.g. in Java EE Oracle tutorial),
but I didn't find any bigger ones (e.g. with databases, 10+ classes, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look [here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmzsN85WJPD5qjqhgix08fZOnkvSaNCaZ) or [there](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmzsN85WJPD4ti81JIMubVavgUw6v8zYg).

The first is a small shopping example with Primefaces and some beans, the second is a soccer database with JSF 2, but also Servlet- and JSP Technology.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [Jboss Quickstarts](http://www.jboss.org/developer/quickstarts.html)? They're not *that* big, but looking at the parts that interested me certainly helped get my feet wet with JavaEE-6.

For JSF, I'd try the [Tasks](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/tasks/) and [Tasks-JSF](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/tasks-jsf/) examples.